# saved search on mobile

Tags: mobile, search

[image: search]

I have been asked to mock up a simple search interface for a mobile device. At first it was search box and search execute button.

business has asked me to include facility for user to run saved searches. I have mocked up an example of how this might look which is the image above.

when the user clicks the disk icon a list of previously saved searches appears which the user can select from to run that search again.

**question**

Is this the best time to list the saved search icon? and

is this the best place to list the saved search?

I am troubled by the placement of the icon but dont know here else to put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the icon. Usually the diskette is the symbol for saving something, not displaying a list. Since you have a lot of space why don't you use a button with label "Saved Searches ...", just below the "Search" button. See image below :

[image]

EDIT by OP

in other parts of the app is an icon that allows you to access the saved search list

[image]

Comment: this is good. on other screens if I want to access my saved searches I had the icon in the nav bar so I'm not sure how this would work now...

Comment: You can add an icon on the "Saved Searches" button. On other screens show only the icon. But try to find some other icon, I think the diskette is misleading.

Comment: of course, that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common for previous searches to appear in a drop down list below the search boxes as soon as focus goes into the box - or even for a dedicated search page, simply to automatically show the saved or recent searches in a list without having to *manually* make that happen.

This then allows the previous searches to be sensibly filtered or ordered as you continue typing.

In such a scenario, the search box needs to be as high as possible in order for the drop down not to appear (and be instantly hidden) underneath the keyboard.

It's also common once the list appears, for an item to allow access to manage the saved searches - eg to clear the list.

You'll see this on a variety of applications and browsers on Mac / Windows - and on mobile.

If not showing the list automatically, then to aid discoverability you could move the icon *inside* the search box so that it's clearly related to the search box rather than a separate chunk of functionality. Having said that, there's usually a 'clear' button inside the right end of the search box, which you haven't included in your mock up...

In any case, although not so important to the main question, I wouldn't use the diskette symbol, perhaps a clock symbol might work better, and then display the age of the saved searches in the list. It's possible to combine 'best matches' and 'saved searches' in the list with separate symbols like in the example below.

Note the clever combined symbol of the magnifying glass and the clock in the first image.

[image]

[image]

<sub>Yeah - grabbed these off Google Images - sorry about the weiner item :-)</sub>

Comment: you could do both: list recent searches on focus and link to dedicated, user controlled saved searches.